# RequireHttps attribute vs Url Rewrite in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I'm trying to enforce https in my Azure MVC app.  So far I see two ways:

1. Use the [RequireHttps] attribute on my Base Controller
2. Rewrite the URL in web.config

Is one better than the other?  It feels like rewriting would be speedier because the request doesn't have to make it to the app, just to IIS, but I'm not sure if that's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is one better than the other? It feels like rewriting would be
>   speedier because the request doesn't have to make it to the app, just
>   to IIS, but I'm not sure if that's true.

Yes, it's true. The earlier you do this, the faster it will be. No need to hit the application layer when this can be handled at a much higher level of the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I would do both -- the rewrite is there mainly to catch folks that forget the https for some reasons so they don't get 404s. The [RequireHttps] is there to ensure someone can't misconfigure the app to not have https.